# Raise SIGINT to gracefully kill jobs in pipeline declarative Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have created declarative pipline using the example:

```
def strings = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

def steps = strings.collectEntries {
    ["echoing ${it}" : trans(it)]
}

steps.failfast = true
parallel steps

def trans(inputString) {
    return {
        node {

            echo inputString // have some code to make the function as failure
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet send the interrupt signal to process to kill the parallel jobs. Instead of kill how do i send sigint signal.